# trim timezone from date in igDateEditor

Tags: javascript, infragistics, ignite-ui

i am using a date field which defined as

```
var input = $('<input id="datefield"/>');

$(input).igEditor({
               type: 3,
               datePattern: 'dd/MM/yyyy'                       
});
```

and i am getting the value as

```
var date=$("#datefield").igEditor("option","value")
```

which gives me date as

date=Sun Jun 05 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (Arabian Standard Time)

but i want date as Sun Jun 05 2011 00:00:00

Is it possible to get date excluding the timezone.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing is the default JavaScript representation of Date object, which is what the editor will use when you specify it to be DateEditor.

To get your result first set the [dataMode property](http://help.infragistics.com/jQuery/2013.1/ui.igdateeditor#options) to either "text" or "editModeText". This will modify the value the editor accepts and returns.

```
$("#datefield").igEditor({
    type: 3,
    dataMode: "text"
});
```

Second - use the [value() method](http://help.infragistics.com/jQuery/2013.1/ui.igdateeditor#methods) as it is modified by dataMode:

```
$("#datefield").igEditor("value")
```

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/damyanpetev/DjwsD/

Side note: the datePattern property you are setting is not correct (it just happens that the default date pattern of the control is the same). You should be using **dateDisplayFormat** instead (in the fiddle as well) where you have predefined date/dateLong/dateTime presets as well as the option to build it yourself exactly like you did with datePattern. The "dateTime" setting is closest to what you want I think and it is modified by the regional settings, but in case it's not perfect I've made you a pattern that matches what you want exactly.

Comment: but now i am getting this error 'Object has no method getTime infragistics.lob.js'.Can you help me with this

Comment: after reloading the grid data.Actually this is due to changing dataMode: "text".while refreshing the grid this error is comming.

Comment: Woah I was assuming a stand-alone editor so far :) I can't quite place how the editor is connected with the grid like this.

Comment: Also, for a grid scenario check out sample: http://www.infragistics.com/products/jquery/sample/grid/editing or docs: http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/jQuery/2013.1/CLR4.0?page=igSparkline_Overview.html . editorOptions maps directly to an editor options, perhaps you should be using that approach instead?

Comment: Actually i am passing a row like this to grid $('#Grid1').igGridUpdating('updateRow', Id, RowData) and RowData=[{name:"ABC",Id:"1",date:"12/3/04"}] and this date value i am getting from the editor.

Comment: Then you had no/different problem to begin with - If you have defined the column as 'date' type in the grid it will expect a Date object for its value and attempt to read its time to produce formatting :) You can try to pass it as new Date("12/3/04"), revert back to the original editor without formatting or if you really need  it define the grid column as string so it would accept the value.